# How do I add a user to TFS Licensed user group?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2010

I can't seem to add a user to the licensed user group in TFS 2010.  Everything online says to open up Visual Studio, connect to the server, then drop down team, click Team Foundation Server Settings, and then Groups.

I can get that far, but then it says to click on the Licensed Users Group, and I don't have that group in my list.

I don't think this should even work really though, because I believe those directions are for TFS 2008 not 2010.

We've got TFS 2010 installed, and on my development PC I'm using VS 2008, and we have another PC in the office using VS 2010 so I can connect to it either way.  I also have full rights to the 2008 server that the TFS is actually installed on, but cannot seem to find the licensed user group anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Are your instructions from Microsoft or an internal document?  I've never seen the `Licensed Users Group` in TFS.  Instead, we add our users to `[SERVER]\Team Foundation Valid Users` when they are licensed.

In Visual Studio 2010, first ensure that you are connected to the Team Foundation Server.  Then, under the `Team` menu, select `Team Project Collection Settings` then `Group Membership`.  This will bring up a dialog box that shows all of the valid groups.  Find the one that is called `[SERVER]\Team Foundation Valid Users` and click on `Properties`.

In the secondary window that pops up, select `Windows User or Group` and click `Add`.

Alternatively, create an Active Directory group that represents your authorized users, and add that group to the `Team Foundation Valid Users` TFS group.  This way, when you add new users, you can have your network administration simply add the licensed user to that Active Directory group and they'll automatically be included in the Valid Users.

Comment: The instructions are from multiple sources... The help menu on the TFS server, Google, Stack Overflow, microsoft's website, etc... How do you access [SERVER]\Team Foundation Valid Users?

Comment: Edited my message to provide instructions on doing this.

Comment: Is it supposed to actually say [SERVER] or my collection name?

Comment: Yes, it is probably the collection name. `[SERVER]` might be on TFS 2008 only.  I don't have access to my 2010 instance right now.

Comment: I do not see [SERVER] on 2008 or 2010, and where I see [<CollectionName>]\Team Foundation Valid Users, it has the buttons to add a new user greyed out.

Comment: yes, I have full admin rights on the 2008 server its installed on, and on the Team Foundation Server itself.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what's been said here, that particular group isn't expected to exist in all editions:

> After you install Team Foundation Server Workgroup Edition, you must add users to Team Foundation Licensed Users security group in order for them to connect to the server. **This security group is a server-level group specific to the Workgroup Edition. This group is created during installation of the Workgroup Edition, but not the Trial Edition or the Standard Edition**

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/how-to-add-users-for-team-foundation-server-workgroup-edition/